# Styling in-line components on select specific item

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onclick, react-hooks

I would like to be able to create some different UI for item I select.

I am using hooks for my selected statement and it works just fine, I just can't make the styling work.

**The current UI** - basic bootstrap cards. **Wished UI** - bootstrap card that has a border around when selected.

My Hooks for detecting the selection (works fine)

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(items.one); // default value
```

And what I tried so far to achieve:

```
                <Card
                    onClick={() => setSelected(items.two)}
                    style={{
                        borderColor: selected ? 'black' : "none",
                    }}
                >
                </Card>
                <Card
                    onClick={() => setSelected(items.three)}
                    style={{
                        borderColor: selected ? 'black' : "none",
                    }}
                >
                </Card>
                ..................
                ..................
```

For each card is the same logic - but it doesn't detect the selection and card has always black border. What I tried to do above is when the specific item is selected give it black border, otherwise none.

Any solution how can I achieve better UI/UX with this ? I have no idea why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Each card is the same logic. So you can use `map` to render. I saw your `items` is object so first, convert items to arrayKey: `const itemsKey = Object.keys(items);`

Next: update render

```
  {itemsKey.map((key, index) => (
    <Card
      key={index}
      data={items[key]}
      onClick={() => setSelected(key)}
      style={{
        borderColor: selected === key ? "black" : "none",
      }}
    />
  ))}
```

Comment: Where is the {index} coming from ? I have it undefined therefore error

Comment: I figured that out what's missing, thanks for update anyway. But it does not print anything else then [Object Object], seems like it doesn't get it.

Comment: I just comment solution. You need to update to match with your project

Comment: So how would you map through individual titles ? - `{items.title}` ?

Comment: What is the content of `items`? If it contains more another infor: I think you should update like this:
<Card
onClick={() => setSelected("two")}
style={{
    borderColor: selected === "two" ? 'black' : "none",
}}
>
</Card>
<Card
onClick={() => setSelected("three")}
style={{
    borderColor: selected === "three" ? 'black' : "none",
}}
>
</Card>